# Receiving garbage values in USART

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart, keil

I wrote a code in bare-metal mode and USART communication in Keil on stm32f107. But it keeps sending garbage while I expect it to send me "HI" repeatedly. Here are my steps:

1. Wrote an initialize function for USART, accessed and enabled APB1ENR and APB2ENR and AFIO -> MAPR and GPIOA -> CRL and two registers of USART itself (BRR for baud rate and CR1).

   (All according to datasheet and reference manual)
2. Wrote a write function and as long as transmit buffer is empty writes letters (chars).
3. And a small pseudo delay function

And I connect a serial cable and use "Tera Term" to view the stuff sent through this usart thing :/

```c
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header

void USART2_ini(void);
void USART_write(int ch);
void delayMS(int delay);

int main(void)
{
    USART2_ini();
    while(1)
    {
        USART_write('H');
        USART_write('I');
        delayMS(100);
    }
}

void USART2_ini(void)
{
    RCC->APB1ENR |= (1 << 17);
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1 << 2);
    RCC->APB2ENR |= 1;              
    AFIO -> MAPR |= (1 << 4);
    GPIOA -> CRL |= 0x00000B00;
    USART2 -> BRR = 0x0341; //Baud rate of 9600 @8MHz
    USART2 -> CR1 |= 0x0008;
    USART2 -> CR1 |= 0x2000; //Enabling USART itself!
}

void USART_write(int ch)
{
    while(!(USART2 -> SR & 0x0080))
        USART2 -> DR = (ch & 0xFF);
}

void delayMS(int delay)
{
    int i;
    for(; delay > 0; delay--)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 3195; i++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually garbage either means wrong baud rate, or wrong data being sent. There is no way we can know which because your question lacks code or at least details on what values you are using.

Comment: 1) post the code 2) I think there are videos on youtube that do exactly that - STM32 UART on registers. You should search for it, probably missed or misconfigured something

Comment: Yes, that happens. Do you have a question? I mean, you don't even mention which baud rate or clock source you are using, and how the MCU is connected to PC for communication. You might have a loose ground wire or RS232 cable when you need a TTL cable or vice versa. Also your previous question about clock source for UART may be the reason for this issue so you basically have two questions open about the same issue, right?

Comment: Output some some 0x55 bytes, that corresponds to 01010101 in binary, and check TXD with a scope to see if your bits are there. The scope will also show the bit rate, start bits, stop bits, etc, so you can check your configuration.

Comment: @Justme yes sir.